# Need to edit swing GUI code for bar chart

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to make a bar chart using java and Swing. I had a look at the code at the link below - 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Simplebarchart.htm

I want to increase the space between bars in this chart. How do I do it?

The code -

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChartPanel extends JPanel {
private double[] values;

private String[] names;

private String title;

public ChartPanel(double[] v, String[] n, String t) {
names = n;
values = v;
title = t;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);
if (values == null || values.length == 0)
  return;
double minValue = 0;
double maxValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (minValue > values[i])
    minValue = values[i];
  if (maxValue < values[i])
    maxValue = values[i];
}

Dimension d = getSize();
int clientWidth = d.width;
int clientHeight = d.height;
int barWidth = clientWidth / values.length;

Font titleFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
FontMetrics titleFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
Font labelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
FontMetrics labelFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(labelFont);

int titleWidth = titleFontMetrics.stringWidth(title);
int y = titleFontMetrics.getAscent();
int x = (clientWidth - titleWidth) / 2;
g.setFont(titleFont);
g.drawString(title, x, y);

int top = titleFontMetrics.getHeight();
int bottom = labelFontMetrics.getHeight();
if (maxValue == minValue)
  return;
double scale = (clientHeight - top - bottom) / (maxValue - minValue);
y = clientHeight - labelFontMetrics.getDescent();
g.setFont(labelFont);

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  int valueX = i * barWidth + 1;
  int valueY = top;
  int height = (int) (values[i] * scale);
  if (values[i] >= 0)
    valueY += (int) ((maxValue - values[i]) * scale);
  else {
    valueY += (int) (maxValue * scale);
    height = -height;
  }

  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.drawRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
  int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(names[i]);
  x = i * barWidth + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
  g.drawString(names[i], x, y);
}
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(400, 300);
double[] values = new double[3];
String[] names = new String[3];
values[0] = 1;
names[0] = "Item 1";

values[1] = 2;
names[1] = "Item 2";

values[2] = 4;
names[2] = "Item 3";

f.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(values, names, "title"));

WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
};
f.addWindowListener(wndCloser);
f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a line of code where you set X coordinates for the bars:

```
int valueX = i * barWidth + 1;
```

To shift each bar further you can change it to:

```
int valueX = i * (barWidth+20) + 1;
```

You can declare a separate class level variable for this:

```
int barSpace = 20;

...//later in paintComponent.
int valueX = i * (barWidth+space) + 1;
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a line of code with calculation of `barWidth`:

```
int barWidth = clientWidth / values.length;
```

To fit your chart in client area you can use the following code:

```
barWidth-= barSpace; //or barWidth-=20;
```

This way you will take some space from each bar

Comment: Thanks. BTW, can you tell me what is the purpose of valueQ and valueP ?

Comment: sorry -  I meant valueX and valueY. I copied same code from another site that calls them P and Q instead :P

Comment: @SuperStar AFAIU they stand for left and top coordinates of upper-left corner of each bar rectangle.

Comment: In the current code, the last bar gets partially hidden. So, I made a modification to overcome that. Now, i have some more problems. So, can I ask you one more question? I think i will make a new question out of it.

Comment: @SuperStar tip: try to paste only relevant code or create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Or at least highlight problematic lines of code.

Comment: Ok I will read that link and try to improve my posts. The only thing that worries me is if my post will get downvoted. If you put little or no code, then that happens.

Comment: @SuperStar Have you read my answer? Especially **UPDATE** part?

Comment: yes, but there is a problem of text alignment when I increase the value of barSpace. I posted it as another question here  - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199490/need-help-to-fix-the-gui