# Need help to fix the GUI

Tags: java, swing

The problem is that the text under the bar chart is not aligned with the bars in the bar chart. How do I make them align properly?

What more could I possibly add as details to this question to make your detector shut up? :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleBarChart extends JPanel {

    private double[] value;
    private String[] languages;
    private String title;
    private int gapBetweenBars = 40;//MODIFICATION - NOT A PART OF ORIGINAL CODE

    public SimpleBarChart(double[] val, String[] lang, String t) {
        languages = lang;
        value = val;
        title = t;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        if (value == null || value.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        double minValue = 0;
        double maxValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (minValue > value[i]) {
                minValue = value[i];
            }
            if (maxValue < value[i]) {
                maxValue = value[i];
            }
        }
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        int clientWidth = dim.width;
        int clientHeight = dim.height;
        int barWidth = clientWidth / value.length;

        barWidth = barWidth / 3;//MODIFICATION - NOT A PART OF ORIGINAL CODE

        Font titleFont = new Font("Book Antiqua", Font.BOLD, 15);
        FontMetrics titleFontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
        Font labelFont = new Font("Book Antiqua", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        FontMetrics labelFontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(labelFont);
        int titleWidth = titleFontMetrics.stringWidth(title);
        int q = titleFontMetrics.getAscent();
        int p = (clientWidth - titleWidth) / 2;
        graphics.setFont(titleFont);
        graphics.drawString(title, p, q);
        int top = titleFontMetrics.getHeight();
        int bottom = labelFontMetrics.getHeight();

        if (maxValue == minValue) {
            return;
        }

        double scale = (clientHeight - top - bottom) / (maxValue - minValue);
        q = clientHeight - labelFontMetrics.getDescent();
        graphics.setFont(labelFont);

        for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            int valueP = j * (barWidth + gapBetweenBars) + 1; //MODIFICATION - NOT A PART OF    ORIGINAL CODE
            int valueQ = top;
            int height = (int) (value[j] * scale);
            if (value[j] >= 0) {
                valueQ += (int) ((maxValue - value[j]) * scale);
            } else {
                valueQ += (int) (maxValue * scale);
                height = -height;
            }
            graphics.setColor(Color.blue);
            graphics.fillRect(valueP, valueQ, barWidth - 2, height);
            graphics.setColor(Color.black);
            graphics.drawRect(valueP, valueQ, barWidth - 2, height);
            int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(languages[j]);
            p = j * barWidth + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
            graphics.drawString(languages[j], p, q);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        double[] value = new double[5];
        String[] languages = new String[5];
        value[0] = 1;
        languages[0] = "Visual Basic";

        value[1] = 2;
        languages[1] = "PHP";

        value[2] = 3;
        languages[2] = "C++";

        value[3] = 4;
        languages[3] = "C";

        value[4] = 5;
        languages[4] = "Java";

        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleBarChart(value, languages, "Programming    Languages"));

        WindowListener winListener = new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
        frame.addWindowListener(winListener);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setGapBetweenBars(int gapBetweenBars) {

        this.gapBetweenBars = gapBetweenBars;
    }

    public int getGapBetweenBars() {

        return this.gapBetweenBars;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. You posted some questions recently where you describe quickly a problem, and then past a big chunk of code. You should try to post questions which are likely to also help other people coming here. Questions like this one are too localized. You should try to narrow down a bit more the problem before asking a question to make it more helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `p` in your for loop is incorrect and should rather be:

```
p = j * (barWidth + gapBetweenBars) + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
```

You forgot to take the gap into account.

Comment: Wow ! It works. What did you do and how did you figure it out?

Comment: @SuperStar your strings were not properly aligned horizontally, meaning that the value of `p` was not correct. After that, it is just basic math: `index of column`/bar times (`width of bar + gap) + (barwidth/2) gives the middle of the column. Then we substract half of the size of the label so that it is centered on the bar. That's all ;-)

Answer (score 3):

use this in side for loop

```
int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(languages[j]);
p = j * (barWidth+gapBetweenBars) + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
```

changed calculation of space between Languages strings